# Insert stored procedure result set into Temp table and query temp table

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sybase, sap-ase

I have the following stored proc which is trying to:

1. Execute system stored procedure (sp_monitorconfig) and put the result set into a temp table.
2. SELECT FROM this temp table and add 2 custom columns (SOURCESERVER & CollectionTime)
3. This final result set will be ingested into Logstash via jdbc job.

I'm currently using SAP ASE 16 (sybase) and **am getting an incorrect syntax error at keyword 'exec'**.  I'm not sure if I have to prefix the stored proc or what, but I'm currently stumped and any help is appreciated.

```
USE db
GO
    CREATE PROCEDURE sp_active_con_ratio.sql AS
    DECLARE @servername varchar(32) DECLARE @collecttime DATETIME DECLARE @procparam varchar(32)
select
    @servername = @@servername
select
    @collecttime = getdate()
select
    @procparam = 'number of user connections' CREATE TABLE #TempUserConnections
    (
        TempName varchar(35),
        FreeConnections int,
        ActiveConnections int,
        PercentActive char(6),
        MaxUsed int,
        Reuse_cnt int,
        Instance_Name varchar(30) NULL
    )
INSERT INTO
    #TempUserConnections (TempName, FreeConnections, ActiveConnections, PercentActive, MaxUsed, Reuse_cnt, Instance_Name)
    exec sp_monitorconfig @procparam  **ERROR HERE**
SELECT
    @servername AS 'SOURCESERVER',
    FreeConnections,
    ActiveConnections,
    PercentActive,
    MaxUsed,
    @collecttime AS 'CollectionTime'
FROM
    #TempUserConnections
    DROP TABLE #TempUserConnections
    RETURN
GO
```

Thanks!

Comment: You don't tell us *what* that error is. Also `sp_` is a reserved prefix by Microsoft and should **not** be used for User Procedures.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for the comment.  Sorry, error is just "Incorrect syntax near the keyword exec."  Also, I altered the db name and sp name because they both included company info :)

Comment: [Check if this help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166080/how-can-i-get-data-from-a-stored-procedure-into-a-temp-table)

Comment: @basement this code is running without error on my environment !.

Comment: `insert / exec` is not supported in Sybase ASE; while you can [use a proxy table to insert proc output into a table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5570045/7366100) this is a bit convoluted; your best bet would be to extract the desired queries from the source of `sp_monitorconfig` and build your own/custom sql to do what you want

Comment: @markp-fuso Thanks for the comment, recreating the query was my initial thought- using sp_helptext on sp_monitorconfig was what I did originally however I could not decipher how it was querying 'max available USER connections'.  Full code here: http://www.sqlbrowser.com/wikiHTML/sqlbhtml/sybsystemprocs/sp_monitorconfig.html

Comment: @basement - thanks for the link/reminder ... I'd forgotten about that optional input parameter that allows storing values in a pre-defined table; see my answer (below) for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd forgotten that `sp_monitorconfig` has an optional input parameter (`@result_tbl_name`) that allows the operator to designate a table into which the results should be inserted.

From the documentation on [sp_monitorconfig](https://help.sap.com/viewer/29a04b8081884fb5b715fe4aa1ab4ad2/16.0.3.7/en-US/ab751635bc2b1014b616b39f5c6f4c24.html), Example #8 ...

First create the table to hold the results; while the table name can vary you'll want to keep the column names/datatypes as defined:

```
create table sample_table
(Name            varchar(35),
 Config_val      int,
 System_val      int,
 Total_val       int,
 Num_free        int,
 Num_active      int,
 Pct_act         char(6),
 Max_Used        int,
 Reuse_cnt       int,
 Date            varchar(30),
 Instance_Name   varchar(35))
```

To capture a few metrics:

```
exec sp_monitorconfig "locks",            sample_table
exec sp_monitorconfig "number of alarms", sample_table
```

Display metrics:

```
-- select * from sample_table

exec sp_autoformat sample_data
go

sp_autoformat sample_table
go

 Name             Config_val System_val Total_val Num_free Num_active Pct_act Max_Used Reuse_cnt Date                Instance_Name
 ---------------- ---------- ---------- --------- -------- ---------- ------- -------- --------- ------------------- -------------
 number of locks       10000        942     10000     9717        283   2.83       308         0 Aug 16 2020 12:26PM              
 number of alarms        400          0       400      386         14   3.50        14         0 Aug 16 2020 12:26PM
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this;

```
USE db
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_active_con_ratio.sql AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @servername varchar(32) = (select @@servername)
    DECLARE @collecttime DATETIME   = (select getdate())
    DECLARE @procparam varchar(32)  = (select 'number of user connections')

    
    CREATE TABLE #TempUserConnections
    (
        TempName varchar(35),
        FreeConnections int,
        ActiveConnections int,
        PercentActive char(6),
        MaxUsed int,
        Reuse_cnt int,
        Instance_Name varchar(30) NULL
    )

    INSERT INTO #TempUserConnections 
    (
        TempName, 
        FreeConnections, 
        ActiveConnections, 
        PercentActive, 
        MaxUsed, 
        Reuse_cnt, 
        Instance_Name
    )

    -- Add the semi-colon to terminate the statement
    EXEC sp_monitorconfig @procparam;

    SELECT
        @servername AS 'SOURCESERVER',
        FreeConnections,
        ActiveConnections,
        PercentActive,
        MaxUsed,
        @collecttime AS 'CollectionTime'
    FROM
        #TempUserConnections
        DROP TABLE #TempUserConnections
END

GO
```

As [@larnu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2029983/larnu) mentioned you should not use the prefix `sp`, a better prefix in my opinion is `usp_`.

Ensure the stored procedure you're calling (`sp_monitorconfig`) has a `RETURN`